# limit and convergence of a summation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I have two related questions here:

Known:

- $q$ is a positive integer
- $s=\frac{3}{\alpha}+\epsilon$
- $k$ is sufficiently large to ensure $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{k^{\alpha}} \le \delta$
- $\alpha > 3$

Questions:

1. $\sum_{q=1}^\infty (q+1)^2\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{q^\alpha}\right)^s < 4^{1+s} \sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{q^2}{q^{\alpha s}} < \infty $, why?
2. Why does the above show $\sum_{q=k}^\infty (q+1)^2\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{q^\alpha}\right)^s \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ with ?

Thanks,

Comment: 2 follows because the series in 1 is convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $q+1\le 2q$ for $q\ge 1$.  Thus, $(q+1)^2\le 4q^2$ for $q\ge 1$ and since $2\sqrt 2<4$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{q=1}^\infty (q+1)^2(2\sqrt 2/q^\alpha)^s &\le \sum_{q=1}^\infty (4q^2)(4/q^\alpha)^s\\\\
&=4^{1+s}\sum_{q=1}\frac1{q^{\alpha s-2}}
\end{align}$$

The series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ converges since we assume that $\alpha s-2=1+\epsilon \alpha >1$ and the series $\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac1{q^\nu}$ converges when $\nu>1$ by the integral test.

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality in 1. follows from the bound

$$(q + 1)^2 (2\sqrt 2)^s < 4^{1 + s} q^2$$

To see that this is true, notice it's equivalent to the inequality

$$(q + 1)^2 < q^2 \cdot \frac{2^{2 + 2s}}{2^{s + s/2}} = q^2 2^{2 + s/2}$$

But for any $q \ge 1$, we have that

$$(q + 1)^2 \le (2q)^2 = 2^2 q^2$$

Finally, $\alpha s - 2 > 1$, so the series is convergent.

---

2. follows from the fact that if a series is absolutely convergent, then its tails tend to zero.

Comment: Super Great Answers!!